# Check case class with Option fields to make sure all of them are None using Shapeless HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a case class (simplified):

```
case class UserData(name: Option[String], age: Option[String]) {
  lazy val nonEmpty = name.isDefined || age.isDefined // TODO
}
```

Can I replace the current implementation of `nonEmpty` check using, for instance, Shapeless' HList in order to enumerate all the fields to check that all of them are set to `None` or at least one has a value?

Answer (score 2):

I think you also check with pure scala using `productIterator`.

```
scala> val data = UserData(None, None)
data: UserData = UserData(None,None)

scala> data.productIterator.forall {
     | case x: Option[_] => x.isDefined
     | case _ =>  false
     | }
res2: Boolean = false

scala> val data = UserData(Some("foo"), Some("bar"))
data: UserData = UserData(Some(foo),Some(bar))

scala> data.productIterator.forall {
     | case x: Option[_] => x.isDefined
     | case _ =>  false // you may throw exception if you are not expecting this case
     | }
res3: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
case class UserData(name: Option[String], age: Option[String]) {
  lazy val isEmpty = this.productIterator.forall(_ == None)
}

UserData(None,None).isEmpty
UserData(None,Some("s")).isEmpty
```

I suppose you want to do different behavior inside case class, if you dont then @pamu answer is what you are looking for.
If you really want to use shapeless you can, but no need.